# static vector in recursion vs global vector

Tags: recursion, static, tree, global

**USING GLOBAL VECTOR**

```
vector<int> r;
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return r;
    inorderTraversal(root->left);
    r.push_back(root->val);
    inorderTraversal(root->right);
    return r;
}
```

I am getting answer for all test cases but when using below code I am getting answer when running separately but when I finally submit test cases are failing(input of empty tree) like I am getting Output for some other input **why is this happenning?**

```
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
    static vector<int> r;
    if(root==NULL)
        return r;
    inorderTraversal(root->left);
    r.push_back(root->val);
    inorderTraversal(root->right);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say the first version works, then I assume your "global" variable is actually an instance variable of a class. In that case that variable is a new variable every time the test suite creates a new instance of the class.

A `static` local variable however will retain its value even when the function is executed on a new instance of the class of which it is a method.

A solution is to not make it `static`, and then overload the method, so it can take that `r` as second parameter:

```cpp
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<int> r;
    return inorderTraversal(root, r);
}

vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root, vector<int> r) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return r;
    inorderTraversal(root->left, r);
    r.push_back(root->val);
    inorderTraversal(root->right, r);
    return r;
}
```